# Unable to perform replication in Bucardo in a Master-Slave setting

Tags: postgresql

When I was trying to perform replication from Master to Server, the replication was able to run on the Master server, but the table in the slave database did not receive and apply the changes.

According to the Bucardo mailing list, to see the schema needed to perform the sync, type the `/dn` command to show it.

On Master side, the command reveals this:

```
 postgres=#\dn
 List of schemas
 Name       |   Owner
 bucardo    |   bucardo
 public     |   postgres
 test       |   postgres
 testschema |   postgres
```

On the Slave side, however:

```
 postgres=#\dn
 List of schemas
 Name       |   Owner
 public     |   postgres
```

Another suggestion is to insert data into the table at the master side, and see if there are changes made on the slave side but there is no change.
And when running `bucardo status` on the master server, it shows this:

```
 PID of Bucardo MCP: 1852
 Name       State       Last Good   Time        Last I/D        Last Bad
 =========================================================================
 Example    Good        Dec 10, 2014    18h 37m 55s 0/0     none 
                           16:10:19
```

But on the slave server the result is:

```
 DBI connect (‘dbname=bucardo’, ‘bucardo’,…) failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied at /usr/local/bin/bucardo line 296
```

I’ve tried removing the recovery.conf file in the slave server so that I can install Bucardo and add the user Bucardo to the database but it failed to do so.

Comment: I removed recovery.conf in the slave server and installed Bucardo. I then tried to perform sync, but at the slave server, I `bucardo status` gave me `No syncs have been created yet.`. I then restored recovery.conf, but doing so gives me the error message `DBD::Pg::db do failed: ERROR: cannot execute LISTEN during recovery at /usr/local/bin/bucardo line 307`, meaning that the slave server has been configured back to a slave. How do I enable replication on the slave side?